# Flask-Mail Mail() instantiated twice

Tags: python, email, flask, web-applications, flask-mail

I am trying to understand this tutorial [code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_mail.htm).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app =Flask(__name__)
mail=Mail(app) # <-- This

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'yourId@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '*****'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app) # <-- This

@app.route("/")
def index():
   msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'yourId@gmail.com', recipients = ['id1@gmail.com'])
   msg.body = "Hello Flask message sent from Flask-Mail"
   mail.send(msg)
   return "Sent"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

At the line 5 and 13, Mail object are instantiated and assigned to mail.
Even if I comment out the first instantiation in line 5, I can still send emails, so can I say it is just a typo, or it is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `mail=Mail(app)` is not needed.  The primary fuctionality in the `Mail()` [constructor](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/blob/master/flask_mail.py#L545) is to read the app configuration.  So since the appropriate app config variables are not set before line 5, the first `Mail()` object  would likely not even work.